# render scene display only last component

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux, tabnavigator

I was working around react native in learning process and i came across a strange bug which display only last component in render scene in react native and i don't what type of this issue to search for google. please help me and lead me to some topic if there already is.

```
render() {
return (

  <Provider store={store}>

     <Navigator
      initialRoute={{ name: 'mainScreen' }}          
      configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}          
      renderScene={RouteMapper}
    />



  </Provider>, <BottomBar />
 );
}
```

here is the bottom bar component code.

```
export const BottomBar= TabNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
},
Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
  },
 },
});
```

The issue is only  showing up in app and the mainscreen newfeed is not showing.

## Added renderscene code portion.

```
const RouteMapper = (route, navigator) => {
 if (route.name === 'mainScreen') {
return (
  <main navigator={navigator} />
);
} 
};
```

Comment: can i see your renderscene ?

Comment: @Codesingh sure, added in que.